# Post method in drf

Tags: django, python-3.x, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am sending a file name using axios from frontend using react js to my DRF api class now, i need to send that file name to my another api class using drf post method and search for file and return file as response.

I tried doing from backend and it worked, but when i try to using the post methods to post my file name i am unable to do it

I am usng Django and drf and my front end as react js

My frontend code looks something like this

```
fetchFile = (value) => {
        const url = `${API}/dashboard/log_file/`;
        const data = {
         info :value
        }
        axios.post(url,{data}
        )
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using formData?
something like this .

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('info', 'hogehoge')
axios.post(url,formData)
```